# Movement slower when canvas is bigger

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Using this code:

```
x = x + (canvas.height/250);
```

which happens every 1 millisecond should add an amount to x in proportion to the canvas size. x is then drawn so therefore x should move down the canvas at the same speed on different screen sizes (the canvas changes size according to the screen size). However the x moves down at different speeds on my ipod and my pc.

If you want to know the full source code and html file the html is [here](http://badlywiredmusic.com/newhangglider.html) and the javascript file linked to it is [here](http://badlywiredmusic.com/script.js).

Comment: If it is supposed to move down with the **same** speed, why do you even do this?

Comment: @php_nub_qq no the canvas is bigger on the ipod as it has greater screen height in pixels so if you just say + 1 each time it will definitely be slower on the ipod as there are more pixels to move through

Comment: Would you mind creating an example over at [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for future reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said in your question that you are calling the function every 1 millisecond. However, some browsers limit the speed of `window.setInterval` so if you made the function call once every 50 milliseconds it would be the same on all devices.

```
window.setInterval(function(){
/// call your function here e.g. add1toxfunction();
}, 50);
```

Answer (score 3):

The change in traversal time is due to a change in draw time.
If the device is, say, two times slower to draw, the increase 
will get done two times less per second, and your object will be
in mid-screen in the slow device when it will have crossed screen in
the other.

To have consistent behavior you must handle your game time.
Then you just have to decide of your objects speed in pixels per milliseconds,
and use the classical equation :

```
pos = pos + speed * (time step)
```

the code looks like :

```
var x = 0;

var speed = canvas.width / 1000 ; // speed in pixels per milliseconds.

var lastTime = 0;

requestAnimationFrame(launchAnimate);     

function animate() {
         requestAnimationFrame(animate);
         var now = Date.now();
         var dt = now - lastTime ;
         lastTime = now ;
         // draw everything
         draw();
         // update everything with this frame time step.
         update(dt);
}

function launchAnimate() {
    lastTime = Date.now() ;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Edit : you can't draw faster than your screen, so on a 60Hz screen, you'll draw at best every 16.666 ms.
Don't be scared by RequestAnimationFrame, it just means : "when the screen is ready, draw the callback that i gave you.".
So you have to re-arm it every time to make your game live.

So for your game, it's time to organize a bit :

- have an update function where you put all the code that updates all things.
- have a draw function that draws everything.
- do not draw in the update (remove the draw calls in moveTrees), and
  do not update in the draw. SEPARATION OF CONCERNS, :-)
- have each update depend on frame time (dt) for all that's related to time (position, speed, acceleration, forces).

  function update( dt ) {
           x = x + speed * dt ;
           moveTrees(dt);
  }

  function draw () {
         drawTrees();
         drawHangGlider();
         drawTrees();
  }

You'll notice i changed the animate function to call draw and update, still you have a bit of work to re-organize things.

Edit 2 : RequestAnimationFrame is widely ok now :

http://caniuse.com/requestanimationframe

(Chrome for Android is ok).

Rq :

```
 // to use rAF, call this function before your game launches
 polyFillRAFNow();


// insert the function in your code.
function polyFillRAFNow() {
    // requestAnimationFrame polyfill
    var w = window;
    var foundRequestAnimationFrame = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || w.msRequestAnimationFrame || w.mozRequestAnimationFrame || w.oRequestAnimationFrame || function (cb) { setTimeout(cb, 1000 / 60); };
    window.requestAnimationFrame = foundRequestAnimationFrame;
}
```

Rq2 : you might be interested in this article i wrote on  the game loop   http://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2013/03/16/thoughts-on-the-javascript-game-loop/

Comment: I'm not using requestAnimationFrame i'm just running that function and drawing it every 1 ms

Comment: also requestAnimationFrame() does not work on some mobile browsers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: nope doesn't work only doing setInterval with a time such as 50 rather than one works i don't know why so confused!!

Comment: i had made two typos in my code, sorry, it is ok now (the dt i computed was in fact -dt). Anyway, here is something close from what you seek, for you to see : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/3YX6y/

Comment: thanks so much for the fiddle i advise you put it in your answer

Answer (score 2):

First, let's think about what this line does:

```
x += canvas.height / 250;
```

The speed of the object is `canvas.height / 250`. The distance is `canvas.height`. We can say that:

```
distance = speed * time
```

We already have `distance` and `speed`, so:

```
time = distance / speed = canvas.height / (canvas.height / 250) = 250 ms
```

**So the object always reaches its destination in 2.5 seconds.** In order to make that happen, you change the speed based on the screen size.

If you want the speed to be the same in all devices, it shouldn't depend on `canvas.height`.

Comment: if i shouldn't rely on canvas.height, what should I rely on?

Comment: That depends. Exactly what is your purpose?

Comment: Obviously this is extremely unfinished but I want the green circles at http://badlywiredmusic.com/newhangglider to move down at the same speed on different devices. The canvas size responds to screen size and the black circle can be controlled with both arrow keys and swipe gestures. The very unfinished script is at http://badlywiredmusic.com/script.js .

Comment: In my opinion, for your game, the time-based approach which you currently use is great.

Answer (score 1):

So basically you want a relative absolute speed depending on the screen size, which would then appear to be the same on different displays. In order to do this you should use percentages, for example:

```
var pixels_in_1_percent = canvas.height/100;
x += pixels_in_1_percent
```

That will increase the speed by `1%` of canvas height, if you want more speed then you have to multiply it

```
x += pixels_in_1_percent * <number_of_percent_to_increase>
```

Hope that helps.